# CSS And JS Path are not found in AWS for laravel application

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

My laravel app is working fine in cpanel,but after hosting to AWS the extranal css and js files are showing 404 error.

I linked thhe css file like this:

```
<link href="{{ url('assets/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ url('assets/css/dark-style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="{{ url('assets/css/transparent-style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ url('assets/css/skin-modes.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Assets is inside public folder

current error ::

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVBeM.jpg)

Comment: I use <link href="{{ URL::asset('public/css/path') }}" rel="stylesheet"> on my project and it works fine - my css and js files are placed inside of the public/css directory

Answer (score 0):

Use asset() function

Example :

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

set asset folder path in .env file

Comment: Already tried , not working for me